# finding the eigenvalue of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am having trouble getting the correct answer and I dont know where I'm messing up. I think I am putting everything together correctly. I have the following matrix and I need to get the eigenvalues"

\begin{bmatrix}3&2&4\\2&0&2\\4&2&3\end{bmatrix}

so

\begin{bmatrix}3-\lambda&2&4\\2&0-\lambda&2\\4&2&3-\lambda\end{bmatrix}

So I would calculate the first determinant

\begin{equation}(3-\lambda)[((0-\lambda)*(3-\lambda))-4)]\end{equation}

and I should get

\begin{equation}-\lambda^3+6\lambda^2-5x-12\end{equation}

Then:

\begin{equation}2[((0-x)(3-x))-4)]\end{equation}

Which should equal:

\begin{equation}2x^2-6x-8\end{equation}

and finally:

\begin{equation}4[(4-((0-\lambda)(4))]\end{equation}

and I should get

\begin{equation}16+16x\end{equation}

Now I group them together:

\begin{equation}(-\lambda^3+6\lambda^2-5x-12)-(2x^2-6x-8) + (16+16x) \end{equation}

And I'm getting

\begin{equation}-x^3-4x^2+15x-4\end{equation}

as opposed to the correct solution:

\begin{equation}-x^3-6x^2+15x+8\end{equation}

I dont know where exactly I'm messing up. Been trying to figure this out for the past hour. Once I can get the correct solution, I shouldnt have a problem finding the eigenvalues. Its just the calculation. Sorry about the length but its driving me nuts.

Comment: Try the Rule of Sarrus for your determinant, as it is $3\times 3$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_Sarrus

Comment: Your second and third terms are incorrect.  It is impossible to have $\lambda^2$ terms in the second and third terms of the expansion by minors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your 2nd determinant is wrong. It should be
$$2[2(3-\lambda)-8]$$
It's 2 $\times$ the determinant of the matrix obtained after removing 1st row and 2nd column.

Answer (score 2):

$$\det(tI-A)=\begin{vmatrix}t-3&-2&-4\\-2&t&-2\\-4&-2&t-3\end{vmatrix}\stackrel{R_3-2R_2}=\begin{vmatrix}\color{red}{t-3}&-2&-4\\\color{red}{-2}&t&-2\\\color{red}0&-2(t+1)&t+1\end{vmatrix}=$$$${}$$

$$=(t-3)\begin{vmatrix}t&-2\\-2(t+1)&t+1\end{vmatrix}+2\begin{vmatrix}-2&-4\\-2(t+1)&t+1\end{vmatrix}=$$

$$=(t-3)(t+1)(t-4)-4(t+1)(1+4)=(t+1)\left[t^2-7t+12-20\right]=$$

$$=(t+1)(t-8)(t+1)=(t+1)^2(t-8)$$

Answer (score 0):

Take $\det(A-\lambda I)=-(\lambda-8)(\lambda+1)^2=0 \implies \lambda=8,-1$.

For a sanity check: since  $A$ is symmetric,  $8=\det(A)=\lambda_1 \lambda_2 \lambda_3=8\cdot(-1)(-1)$, which agrees with the calculation.